# How can I lock my computer with AutoHotkey?

Tags: window, autohotkey, lockscreen

I'm trying to bind "Esc" key to lock my computer with AutoHotkey.

Manually pressing `Winkey + l` will lock my computer, but it doesn't work in my AutoHotkey script.

```
esc::
   MsgBox Going to lock
   Send, #l
Return
```

I have tried multiple other AutoHotkey syntax (without the modifier for example) without success.

Comment: but I'm not in locked screen screen mode ! I'm in satndard window, and I want to trigger locked scren mode via AHK

Comment: Ah. I see! `DllCall("LockWorkStation")` instead of `send #l`

Answer (score 20):

Per the recommendation in the comments [by wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314908/autohotkey-send-winkey-l#comment71783812_42314908):

```
Esc::
{
DllCall("LockWorkStation")
}
return
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `Esc::DllCall("LockWorkStation")`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in that code, is pressing the windows key first and then the 'l' key. Not both at the same time. To make key combinations, you need to press the combination key down and then the key you want to combine it with. Remember to release the key afterwards. Your code would then look like:

```
Send {LWin down}
Send l
Send {LWin up}
```

or

```
Send {LWin down}l{LWin up}
```

Comment: As much as I like this potential solution in that it doesn't require knowledge of a new function, I tried it out and it just didn't work.

Comment: @plu You have to `Send "{Blind}"` first. [Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Blind) explicitly mention protection against accidental Win+L, and Blind disables it. Also quotes are needed. Try `#J::Send "{Blind}{LWin down}L{LWin up}"`

Comment: @Veraellyunjie  I tried it and it resulted in simply inputting text "L" when I press the #J (windows key + J) buttons. It did not result in getting to the Windows Lock screen.

Comment: @plu Try `#J::Send "{Blind}{j up}l{LWin up}"` - or `RWin up` depending on your keyboard. If it doesn't help, add KeyHistory, you'll need 4 lines, 1st: `#J::{`, 2nd: `Send "{Blind}{j up}l{LWin up}"`, 3rd: `KeyHistory`, 4th: `}`. KeyHistory will show you sequence of keys pressed and simulated. Also check isn't Win+L [disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1059511/how-to-disable-winl-in-windows-10) and does it lock workstation. Also ensure [only one instance of AHK owns the keyboard](https://old.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/saubys/unable_to_send_windows_key_to_open_the_start_menu/htw1ras/)

Comment: @Veraellyunjie // I appreciate the response. For me, the simplicity and easier reproducibiility of "wOxxOm" / "David Metcalfe" 's response are good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just improving the code of my fellow camarades, you can block AND turn off the screen if you want to:

```
#J::
    KeyWait LWin
    KeyWait J
    DllCall("LockWorkStation")
    SendMessage 0x0112, 0xF170, 2,, "Program Manager"
    Return
```

Comment: for those wondering about SendMessage parameters, the exact same snippet is in [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SendMessage.htm#Examples) - "0x0112 is WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF170 is SC_MONITORPOWER"

Comment: For me to make it work, I had to enclose the commands in braces `{`,`}` and quote `"`, `"` keynames in KeyWait. Thus: 1st line `#J::{`, 2nd line `KeyWait "LWin"`, 3rd line `KeyWait "J"`, and add a new line `}` at the end